# Johansen Cointegration Test in R

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I know its probably been asked bevor but i just don't get it.
I have 2 values (Oil and corn price) and i want to check if they are cointegrated. Bevor that, i have tested if they really are non stationarity (and they are assuming to ADF,KPSS and PP).

## Eigen Test

The value of the test statistic is: 3.17 10.9942

```
              10pct  5pct  1pct
     r <= 1 |  7.52  9.24 12.97
     r = 0  | 13.75 15.67 20.20
```

The first test stats say that:
$H_0$ should be that there is no cointegration at all, but:

10.9942 < 15.67 --> $H_0$ to be rejected -> cointegration exists.

What does the second line say?

## Trace Test

The value of the test statistic is: 3.17 14.1641

```
              10pct  5pct  1pct
     r <= 1 |  7.52  9.24 12.97
     r = 0  | 17.85 19.96 24.60
```

What does this test tell me? Where is the difference?
If i know that there is one cointegration, which one is the dependent one?

I appreciate your help!